# How do I create a for loop for this Guessing game?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I literally don't know how to word this, that's why the questions seems a bit weird or beginner-like. I am creating a guessing game for my Java class assignment and I'm having trouble on one part.

This is the whole code I have thus far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class GuessingGame{ 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        System.out.println("Welcome to the greatest Guessing Game known to mankind!");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("You will be guessing what number I am guessing by entering your guess.");
        System.out.println("The number will be between 1 to 100\n");

        Scanner start = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you want to start the game?(1 for Yes, 2 for fun facts before starting the game!)\n");
        int getStart = start.nextInt();

        // testing random number generator
        //System.out.println(Math.random() * 100);

        if(getStart == 1)
        {
            Process();
        }

    }

    public static void Process ()
    {
        int max = 100;
        int min = 1;

        Random ranNum = new Random();
        int ActualNum = min + ranNum.nextInt(max);
        System.out.println(ActualNum);

        //for(int i = getGuess; i == ActualNum; i++)
        //{
        Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nI am thinking of a number...");
        System.out.println("What's your guess?\n");
        int getGuess = guess.nextInt();

        if (getGuess < ActualNum)
        {
            System.out.println("Higher!");
        }

        if (getGuess == ActualNum)
        {
            System.out.println("\nCorrect! You've won!");
        }   
        //}

    }
}
```

As you can see, I commented off the For loop section but I am trying to create a for loop so it gets getGuess, which is the user input, until the user gets it correct. I want it to continue giving the "Guess higher!" or "Guess lower!" hints each time the user inputs a number without it running it through once and finishing the program.

Thank you, I hope the way I worded the question makes sense. I am a beginner who needs help. :)

Btw: I am aware I am printing out the number they have to guess. I was just testing something out.

Comment: you mean something like: while (getGuess != ActualNum) ? you may want to read up on naming conventions, too

Comment: Ah, this makes  a whole lot of sense now. I totally forgot about while. Thanks for the response. Appreciate it.

Comment: also, I will look into naming conventions. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like this

```
    int getGuess = 0;

    while (getGuess != actualNum) {

        System.out.println("What's your guess?\n");
        Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);
        getGuess = guess.nextInt();


        if (getGuess < actualNum) {
            System.out.println("Higher!");
        }

        if (getGuess == actualNum) {
            System.out.println("\nCorrect! You've won!");
        }
    }
```

Output would be like this:
[image: Output of the program]

Comment: Ah, this makes  a whole lot of sense now. I totally forgot about while. Thanks for the response. Appreciate it.

Comment: I just tried it out and came across an error. Instead of just saying "Oops! That's not it, try again" once, it prints it out a whole bunch of times. How do I end it at 1?

Comment: edited, also changed your int Actualnum to actualNum for variable naming convention in Java :)

Comment: not sure if you forgot to answer my reply to your answer. I did that but now it just outputs "Higher!" hundreds of times. Clearly because it is false until the number is correct but I want it to display "higher" or "lower" once and then allow the user to enter their next guess.

Comment: When i run this in my IntelliJ it does excactly that :) How do you run it?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to change the scope of your getGuess variable and use a while loop. This way you can check the value every time you try to enter the loop. Initialize the value to something that won't make the check (e.g. 0 as this is not in [1,100]).

```
[...]
int getGuess = 0;
Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);

while(getGuess != ActualNum)
{
    System.out.println("\nI am thinking of a number...");
    System.out.println("What's your guess?\n");
    getGuess = guess.nextInt();

    if (getGuess < ActualNum)
    {
        System.out.println("Higher!");
    }

    if (getGuess == ActualNum)
    {
        System.out.println("\nCorrect! You've won!");
    }
}
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I remove the "Im thinking of a number... what's your guess" code, it just prints "Higher!" hundreds of times without stopping. How do I make it only print once and then get the next guess?

Comment: Works when I test it